# Line style with alternating dots and long dashes

Tags: qgis, style

[image]

I´m trying to create that personalized style for hidrography representation (in blue at the Picture); the lines must have 0.2 mm of edge, 3 mm of length, the space between lines must be 1.5 mm and the points, with 0.4 mm of size, must be between in the center of all between-lines spaces. Anybody could teach me how to build that style?

So far, i did this in the Picture. The first point is in the right place. After that everything is in the wrong place:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: I´m new in QGIS usage, I don´t know much about the program, and never started to code. Until now I´ve tried to build the style, but the points never go to where I want. 
The best I did is that:

Comment: It was supposed to have a Picture after my "that" in the last comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This style has two components: a dashed-line and a marker on top of it.

You start by creating a simple line, and you select a custom dash pattern. Make sure it is in millimeters. You set 3 dash and 1.5 space. Set the width and color.

Then, using the Plus sign, you add a second marker line. You select it as a point, set the width and color. The tricky part is to locate it properly: the middle of the space are 3+1.5 mm away from each other, so your point should be placed every 4.5mm. Since you don't want it at the beginning of the dash line but in the middle of the space, you need to offset the location by 3 + 1.5/2 = 3.75 mm

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry by the late answer, I was working in another projetcs the last two weeks.
I just wanna thank you! Success, the simbol worked!!!

Comment: @ThiagoMenezes Great! Please consider accepting the answer so others know the solution is valid (green check mark to the left)