# qgis place marker in dashed line

Tags: qgis, symbology

I would like to create a marker line in which a font marker is placed within a dashed line space at equal intervals.  Something like [line-style-with-alternating-dots-and-long-dashes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259524/line-style-with-alternating-dots-and-long-dashes)

c - c - c -

I can get this to somewhat work by creating a marker line with a custom dash pattern:
Dash=10 Space=3 mm
Then setting the font marker with a interval of 13mm and offset of 11.5 (midpoint of space).

The problem I have is that it appears that when the line become more complex there appears to be a misalignment of the dash space and marker offset

[image: Example Marker Space Misalignment]

Regards

Answer (score 6):

It seems you are using a lower case `c`, with a `line offset` (not to be confused with `offset along line`...) in order to align the `c` with the line. This offset breaks the alignment with the line when the line orientation changes.

All offsets, beside the one `along line`, are **not** offsets from the standard position per se, but are rather placed on a new line that received the desired offset. As a consequence, the line geometry is modified (the line length is affected) and the final marker location is not optimal.

Instead, you can use a capital `C` that has an alignment similar to the one on your image, no `line offset` and a smaller symbol size if you wish.

---

Issue with `line offset`:

[image]

Alternative solution without a `line offset`:
[image]