# Custom line style in QGIS

Tags: style, qgis-2.18

Is it possible de create a custom line style in QGIS, as mentioned in the attached file?[image]

Comment: Have a look at : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285456/qgis-place-marker-in-dashed-line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the most straight forward way to achieved that is with *Labels* (in *Layer Properties*) on top of a simple line symbol:

- activate labeling for that layer and choose the field to be used as labels
- set font size in *Text* tab
- in *Background* tab, check *Draw Background* and

  - set *Shape* to `Rectangle`
  - set *Size Type* to `Buffer`
  - set *Size X* to your liking
  - set *Fill Color* to your map canvas' background color
- in *Placement* tab

  - check `On line` for *Allowed positions*
  - set *Repeat* to your liking

These are the minimal settings to get a similar style as in your picture. What happens here is simple: the value of the chosen field will be placed above a colored rectangle at the desired interval, overlaying the line symbol.
You should play around with the multitude of settings in the *Labels* tab, try to get familiar with the possibilities. The placement settings get more complicated when labels of different lines overlap etc.
One note to units: using scale sensitive units (e.g. *Map Units*, *Meter at Scale*) rather than absolute (e.g. *mm*) will ensure a fixed size over all scales (e.g. labels get smaller when you zoom out); might be want you want.

Comment: You have right. When the length feature is short, the label buffer hides the line and the componants of other layers.

Comment: @ennine yep. one easy way could be to only allow labels on lines with a certain length; you´d need to find an acceptable threshold, switch to *Rule Based Labeling*, set up a new rule (your settings should be copied) and type `$length > your_value` in the *Filter* field. there are other, data driven options, but at some point you will enter the realm of *Cartographic Generalization*, and that is a meticulous profession, done by hand... btw., QGIS 3.x comes with a *very* handy label moving tool

Comment: Very interesting suggestion "Rule Based Labeling" which seems a good solution for short lines. Many thanks

Comment: @ennine also, if you only want the line to disappear (because you only have lines on e.g. white background), you could assign a negative value to *Size Y* of the label's background, making it only slighty bigger than the line width (careful with bends, though, you need to adjust accordingly); that way you might be able to avoid the label's background covering other components (it might only be possible with `Fixed` as *Shape*, not sure right now).

Comment: In my case, the rule based on length resolves all my issues. My best thanks